# Carregar ComboBox a partir de uma tabela MySQL - Manipular chave e outro campo

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, combobox

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idLocalidade   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| localidadeNome | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

No XAML uma ComboBox;

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selecaoComboBox"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" SelectionChanged="selecaoComboBox_SelectionChanged"  />
```

Carrego os dados da tabela para a ComboBox desta forma:

```
    private void carregarComboBox()
    {
        MySqlConnection ligacaoBD = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stringDeLigacaoDB"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            ligacaoBD.Open();
            var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT idLocalidade, localidadeNome FROM localidade", ligacaoBD);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "localidade");
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            selecaoComboBox.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)dt).GetList();
            selecaoComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "localidadeNome";
            selecaoComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "idLocalidade";
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ligacaoBD.Close();
        }
    }
```

De seguida pretendo preencher duas TextBox com os dados de cada registo, sempre que é selecionado um valor na ComboBox.
A versão incompleta é esta:

```
    private void selecaoComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        idLocalidadeTextBox.Text = selecaoComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        localidadeNomeTextBox.Text = selecaoComboBox.Text;
    }
```

O campo idLocalidade consigo obter, mas o mesmo já não se aplica ao campo localidadeNome, que é uma string vazia!
O que falha nesta abordagem?

Comment: Estranho! Ao selecionar um item pela segunda vez, aparece-me o texto do anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Das soluções que encontrei esta pareceu-me a mais simples.
Bastou alterar o manipulador de evento:

```
    private void selecaoComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selecaoComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            idLocalidadeTextBox.Text = selecaoComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            localidadeNomeTextBox.Text = selecaoComboBox.Text;
        }
    }
```

Só ainda não percebi porque razão o selecaoComboBox.Text me ia sempre buscar o valor anterior no exemplo inicial!